# How to break setInterval to launch another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to auto reload div in my site. If I click to bottom the script reload another div when i use clearInterval to stop `interval1` it not working the script reload again `interval1` ,when i use console.log interval i find false and the script reload again clearInterval not working or??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var interval2;
  var interval1;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var get_template = function() {
      $("#live-grouped-odds-current").load("template.php");
    }
    interval2 = setInterval(get_template, 6000);
    $("#live_details").click(function() {
      clearInterval(interval2);
      console.log(interval2);
      $('#live-overview-menuitem').removeClass('Actual');
      $('#live_details').addClass('Actual');
      $("#button_sp").css('display', 'none');
      $("#button_dt").css('display', 'block');
      clearInterval(interval2);
      interval2 = false;
      $("#live-grouped-odds-current").empty();
      $("#loader12").css('visibility', 'visible');
      $("#live-grouped-odds-current").load("details.php");
    });
    $("#loader12").css('visibility', 'visible');
    $.get("details/events.php", function(data1) {
      $("#event_list").html(data1);
    });

    $("#loader12").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    var refresh = function() {
      $.get("details/events.php", function(data1) {
        $("#event_list").html(data1);
      });
      $.get("details/simple_event.php", function(data) {
        $("#simple_event").html(data);
      });
    }
    interval1 = setInterval(refresh, 6000);
  });

  function simple_event(id) {
    clearInterval(interval1);
    $('.Event').removeClass('Actual');

    $("#" + id).attr('class', 'Actual');
    $("#simple_event").empty();
    $("#loader12").css('visibility', 'visible');
    $.get("details/simple_event.php?id=" + id, function(data) {
      $("#simple_event").html(data).hide();
      $("#simple_event").slideDown(1000);
      //alert( "Load was performed." );
      $("#loader12").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
    interval1 = setInterval(refresh, 6000);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Format the JS and show HTML

Comment: You are clearing "interval" with is never set? You have a interval2 var which is never used as well? Not sure what the code is trying to do...

Comment: i update my script

Comment: You question is still hard to understand, please show the HTML as well and update your question so we can understand what div, button etc you are referring to. It would be best if you paste your code in a JSFiddle and share it so we can see what the problem is and what you are expecting to happen

Comment: when i click to #live_details i want to clear interval 2 an set interval 1 an still but clearinterval 2 not working it still reloding template.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call clearTimeout it means the interval will not be triggered again, but if `$("#live-grouped-odds-current").load("template.php");` is still running it will complete. If `$("#live-grouped-odds-current").load("template.php");` takes more time than 6000ms you will begin to do multiple request in parallel as well. (It would be better to use setTimeout I think)

Once you call clearInterval(interval2) the first time, set interval2 to **undefined**

```
$("#live_details").click(function() {
  clearInterval(interval2);
  inteval2 = undefined;
});
```

and change **get_template** to

```
var get_template = function() {
  $.get("template.php", function( data ) {
    if (inteval2 !== undefined) {
      $("#live-grouped-odds-current").html( data );
    }
  });
}
```

so `#live-grouped-odds-current` won't be undated if the interval has been cleared